# Bundling an Angular2 app using JSPM

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, jspm, systemjs

I am trying to create a bundle for an Angular2 app.
Here is my jspm config file: https://gist.github.com/ivanbatic/fa4f2d76b44e0204f21d

When I start the app, although it starts 390 HTTP requests in order to render the "Hello World" string, it works.

So...I'm trying to create a bundle using `jspm bundle app build.js --inject'`

Afterwards, I get the following errors:
[image: js errors]

Any suggestions on how to fix these?

Comment: A working example might help: TypeScript: https://github.com/jackfranklin/ng2-jspm-typescript, JS: https://github.com/htdt/ng2-jspm

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript does not yet have bundling support in jspm.
It can be used with dynamic modules loading.
Traceur or babel transpiler can be used for bundle.
*(jspm 0.16.0-beta.3)*

Comment: JSPM now supports TypeScript.